# How to use intercept-url pattern and access?

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, spring-security

I am using Spring security but i don't understand very well how intercept-url works. Here is my spring security config file :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<beans xmlns="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans"
    xmlns:security="http://www.springframework.org/schema/security"
    xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xmlns:jdbc="http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans
http://www.springframework.org/schema/beans/spring-beans-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security
http://www.springframework.org/schema/security/spring-security-3.2.xsd
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc
http://www.springframework.org/schema/jdbc/spring-jdbc-3.2.xsd">

    <!-- configuration des urls  -->
    <security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/*" access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:form-login/>
    </security:http>


    <security:authentication-manager alias="authenticationManager">
        <security:authentication-provider ref="authenticationProvider" />
    </security:authentication-manager>

    <bean id="authenticationProvider"
       class="org.springframework.security.authentication.dao.DaoAuthenticationProvider">
        <property name="userDetailsService" ref="userDetailsService" />
    </bean>

    <bean id="userDetailsService"
        class="com.nexthome.app.security.UserDetailsServiceImpl" />


</beans>
```

With this configuration, i cannot access without being authenticated. So when accessing the url `http://localhost:8080/nexthome` displays a spring login form (`http://localhost:8080/nexthome/spring_security_login`).
But when i change the  to . I am able to access to `http://localhost:8080/nexthome/user/login` without login.

My aim is to protected some url :

```
http://localhost:8080/nexthome  all people must access
http://localhost:8080/nexthome/login  all people must access ( how to display spring login form when trying to access the url?)
http://localhost:8080/nexthome/logout  access to ROLE_USER and ROLE_ADMIN
```

Thanks for your help

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I've found the answer to my question :

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/register"
            access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/login*"
            access="ROLE_USER" />
        <security:intercept-url pattern="/logout*"
            access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
        <security:form-login/>
 </security:http>
```

Now the url 
    `http:localhost:8080/nexthome` is free access 
    `http:localhost:8080/nexthome/regsiter` is free access 
    `http:localhost:8080/nexthome/login` prompt the Spring Security login form before accessing the ressource 
    `http:localhost:8080/nexthome/logout` prompt the Spring Security login form before accessing  the ressource

Answer (score 2):

The pattern attribute on the `security:intercept-url` tag uses [Ant paths](http://ant.apache.org/manual/dirtasks.html#patterns).  Under this syntax `.` has no meaning except for a literal `.`.  So the pattern is most likely not recognized by Spring security and ignored.

If you want to require authentication for the `/nexthome/logout` url but not `/nexthome/login` and `/nexthome` you can use the following configuration:

```
<security:http auto-config="true">
    <intercept-url pattern="/nexthome" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/nexthome/login" access="IS_AUTHENTICATED_ANONYMOUSLY"/>
    <intercept-url pattern="/nexthome/logout" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
    <security:form-login/>
</security:http>
```

Comment: I have added your suggested code but now i can access all page without authentication. I can access :the home page /nexthome. But i can access also login ( without prompting the spring security auto generated form) and logout is accessible without login. I think i missed something

Comment: kevin bowersox found.

Answer (score 0):

In form-login use login-page like this

```
<securityform-login login-page="/login" >
```

If no login URL is specified, Spring Security will automatically create a login URL at /
 spring_security_login.

For logout purpose use

```
<intercept-url pattern="/nexthome/logout" access="ROLE_USER,ROLE_ADMIN" />
```

Comment: Spring login form is not created when i clicked on link /nexthome/logout.